# How to use multiple delimiters to put objects into array

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to use a delimiter to begin the construction of a new object from a text file source.

An example of the txt data that I am using:

> "1|Fred|Fish|fredfish@gamer.net|Ithroeann:2|Laurie|Nash|laurieeenash@gmail.com|Mazzzap:"

This is what I have so far to create the first object in the array, but I am wondering how to use the ":" as the second delimiter to build the second object.
I am thinking about using a loop to automate this process.

```
public class PlayerReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("commandline.txt"));
        input.useDelimiter("|");
        Player[] players = new Player[0];
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String id = input.next();
            String firstName = input.next();
            String lastName = input.next();
            String emailAddress = input.next();
            String gamerTag = input.next();
            Player newPlayer = new Player(id, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, gamerTag);
            players = addPlayer(players, newPlayer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `String#split` is always a good friend. You can use it on `gamerTag` and `split(":")` it.

Comment: Sooo... what exactly is the problem? is the code not working? Also: i would strongly advice you to switch off of an array for variable length input (Use `Set` or `List` instead)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about how to deal with the fact that your file has two delimiters -> | separating fields and : separating objects that contain fields.

It should be straightforward. Try following:

Read the entire file content in string.

`String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("commandline.txt")));`

Separate the objects delimited by :

`String[] objects = content.split(":");`

Create a new empty list of your objects - players:

`List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();`

Convert each object into player by using your business mapping and add each player thus obtained to the above list.

```
for (String object : objects) {
   String[] fields = object.split("|");
   player.add(new Player(fields[0], fields[1], ...);
}
```